# Get waterfall plot values of a feature in a dataframe using shap package

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, random-forest, shap

I am working on a binary classification using random forest model, neural networks in which am using SHAP to explain the model predictions. I followed the tutorial and wrote the below code to get the waterfall plot shown below

With the help of Sergey Bushmanaov's SO post [here](https://I%20am%20working%20on%20a%20binary%20classification%20using%20random%20forest%20model,%20neural%20networks%20in%20which%20am%20using%20SHAP%20to%20explain%20the%20model%20predictions.%20I%20followed%20the%20tutorial%20and%20wrote%20the%20below%20code%20to%20get%20the%20waterfall%20plot%20shown%20below), I managed to export the waterfall plot to dataframe. But this doesn't copy the feature values of the columns. It only copies the shap values, expected_value and feature names. But I want feature names as well. So, I tried the below

```
shap.waterfall_plot(shap.Explanation(values=shap_values[1])[4],base_values=explainer.expected_value[1],data=ord_test_t.iloc[4],feature_names=ord_test_t.columns.tolist())
```

but this threw an error

> TypeError: waterfall() got an unexpected keyword argument
> 'base_values'

I expect my output to be like as below. I have used background of 1 point to compute base value. But you are free to use background 1,10 or 100 as well. In the below output, I have stored the values and feature in one column called `Feature`. This is something similar to `LIME`. But not sure whether SHAP has this flexibility to do this?

[image]

**update - plot**

[image]

****update code - kernel explainer waterfall to dataframe****

```
masker = Independent(X_train, max_samples=100)
explainer = KernelExplainer(rf_boruta.predict,X_train)
bv = explainer.expected_value
sv = explainer.shap_values(X_train)

sdf_train = pd.DataFrame({
    'row_id': X_train.index.values.repeat(X_train.shape[1]),
    'feature': X_train.columns.to_list() * X_train.shape[0],
    'feature_value': X_train.values.flatten(),
    'base_value': bv,
    'shap_values': sv.values[:,:,1].flatten()   # i changed this to pd.DataFrame(sv).values[:,1].flatten()
})
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try following:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from shap import TreeExplainer, Explanation
from shap.plots import waterfall

import shap
print(shap.__version__)

X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True, as_frame=True)
model = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=5, n_estimators=100).fit(X, y)
explainer = TreeExplainer(model)
sv = explainer(X)
exp = Explanation(sv.values[:,:,1], 
                  sv.base_values[:,1], 
                  data=X.values, 
                  feature_names=X.columns)
idx = 0
waterfall(exp[idx])
```

---

```
0.39.0
```

[image]

Then:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'row_id':idx,
    'feature': X.columns,
    'feature_value': exp[idx].values,
    'base_value': exp[idx].base_values,
    'shap_values': exp[idx].values
})
```

---

```
#expected output
row_id  feature feature_value   base_value  shap_values
0   0   mean radius -0.035453   0.628998    -0.035453
1   0   mean texture    0.047571    0.628998    0.047571
2   0   mean perimeter  -0.036218   0.628998    -0.036218
3   0   mean area   -0.041276   0.628998    -0.041276
4   0   mean smoothness -0.006842   0.628998    -0.006842
5   0   mean compactness    -0.009275   0.628998    -0.009275
6   0   mean concavity  -0.035188   0.628998    -0.035188
7   0   mean concave points -0.051165   0.628998    -0.051165
8   0   mean symmetry   -0.002192   0.628998    -0.002192
9   0   mean fractal dimension  0.001521    0.628998    0.001521
10  0   radius error    -0.021223   0.628998    -0.021223
11  0   texture error   -0.000470   0.628998    -0.000470
12  0   perimeter error -0.021423   0.628998    -0.021423
13  0   area error  -0.035313   0.628998    -0.035313
14  0   smoothness error    -0.000060   0.628998    -0.000060
15  0   compactness error   0.001053    0.628998    0.001053
16  0   concavity error -0.002988   0.628998    -0.002988
17  0   concave points error    0.000140    0.628998    0.000140
18  0   symmetry error  0.001238    0.628998    0.001238
19  0   fractal dimension error -0.001097   0.628998    -0.001097
20  0   worst radius    -0.050027   0.628998    -0.050027
21  0   worst texture   0.038056    0.628998    0.038056
22  0   worst perimeter -0.079717   0.628998    -0.079717
23  0   worst area  -0.072312   0.628998    -0.072312
24  0   worst smoothness    -0.006917   0.628998    -0.006917
25  0   worst compactness   -0.016184   0.628998    -0.016184
26  0   worst concavity -0.022500   0.628998    -0.022500
27  0   worst concave points    -0.088697   0.628998    -0.088697
28  0   worst symmetry  -0.026166   0.628998    -0.026166
29  0   worst fractal dimension -0.007683   0.628998    -0.007683
```

`RandomForest` is a bit special, this is why. When something fails with the new plots API, try to feed `Explanation` object.

**UPDATE**

To explain a single datapoint `exp_id` vs a single background datapoint `back_id` (i.e. to answer question "why prediction for `exp_id` differes from prediction for `back_id`"):

```
back_id = 10
exp_id = 20
explainer = TreeExplainer(model, data=X.loc[[back_id]])
sv = explainer(X.loc[[exp_id]])
exp = Explanation(sv.values[:,:,1], sv.base_values[:,1], data=X.loc[[back_id]].values, feature_names=X.columns)
waterfall(exp[0])
```

[image]

Finally, as you asked for everything in the suggested format:

```
from shap.maskers import Independent
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)

model = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=5, n_estimators=100).fit(X_train, y_train)

masker = Independent(X_train, max_samples=100)
explainer = TreeExplainer(model, data=masker)
bv = explainer.expected_value[1]
sv = explainer(X_test, check_additivity=False)

pd.DataFrame({
    'row_id': X_test.index.values.repeat(X_test.shape[1]),
    'feature': X_test.columns.to_list() * X_test.shape[0],
    'feature_value': X_test.values.flatten(),
    'base_value': bv,
    'shap_values': sv.values[:,:,1].flatten()
})
```

but I'd definitely not show this to my mom.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Upvoted. Accepted. Instead of passing a row index 0, is it possible to pass full dataframe?

Comment: like in expected output, you cam see we have two different rows. Since, I have a big data, was wondering whether there would be any way. Would really be helpful if you can edit your code to show that? Am not sure whether looping is the only option. Then, it may take time. Isn't it?

Comment: And I see that, you don't really use background information. So, the base value is same for all observation. Isbit possible to consider only 1 instance as background, so Shap computation os faster if I have to iterate over all rows.?

Comment: Gimme some time to do like in your example (for the whole df)

Comment: I think your code still provides/stores output for a single row at a time. Am I right? We have to use for loop to ierate through full dataframe of 10000 rows in test data? Moreover, we want the explanations of both the classes (0 and 1) for full dataframe. Like shown in my expected output which has both +ve and _ve values along with feature values as well.

Comment: `I think your code still provides/stores output for a single row at a time. `. Yes. `We have to use for loop to ierate through full dataframe of 10000 rows in test data`. No. You can do it at once.

Comment: And you asked waterfall with background. This is why.

Comment: `back_id` id of a point to use as a background, which is necessary to provide base. `exp_id` is id of a datapoint to explain.

Comment: So, currently it chooses 1 data point (which is 10th data point) as a background to provide base values for all observations. Am I right? Wouldn't this give us the same base value for all observations? because we are using the same background data point to calculate base values?

Comment: 2nd, if you don't mind, can you show me how can I pass full dataframe as exp_id instead of a single data point?

Comment: `So, currently it chooses 1 data point (which is 10th data point) as a background to provide base values for all observations.` Yes. `I was of the understanding that each observation will have different base value.` No, and it caught my attention when you prepared expected output. `2nd, if you don't mind, can you show me how can I pass full dataframe as exp_id instead of a single data point? ` I do suggest you read notebooks (and accompanying papers) at https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html.

Comment: @I was going through docs. One quick question. I see that positive feature contributions indications feature impact towards `class 1`. For ex: for class 0, I see 4 features with negative values as such as `-0.1`, `-0.1` , `0.3`, `0.15` and base value us `0.2`. Does this mean `feature with largest negative value` indicate highest influence on outcome variable? or it is the opposite? Because, I know in negative world, the more larger in magnitude (ex: -20), is lesser than -1.

Comment: Should we interpret negative values that way? or SHAP just adds negative sign to indicate predictions for class 0 and we should still go with magnitude? Meaning, `-20.0` is larger than `-1.0`?

Comment: Class `1` in probability world is usually defined through sigmoid (or hinge, or tanh, or something similar), meaning the higher the input, the higher the probability of 1. For sigmoid threshold is .5, I believe: anything higher than that is considered 1, and vice versa. So, answering your question, a feature with highest absolute value has highest impact on outcome. The sign determines direction of the impact.

Comment: Yeah, so mathematical comparison of values does not apply here. Meaning, -20 is smaller than -1 (correct in mathematical world but doesnt apply in SHAP interpreattaion)?

Comment: I think there is no different mathematics in SHAP: -20 is still less than -1. But it will be shown higher in plot because plot shows abs. I'll do full df, gimme some time.

Comment: I updated my post with a sample plot. Let's say we have 6 features. `F1 to F6`. F1 is at the top and F6 is at the bottom. Now, can we interpret it this way? - Among all the 4 features that moves this prediction to class 0, it is `F6` feature that has the maximum impact (on moving this prediction to class 0)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping with the full dataframe. I can award a bounty if that is applicable/allowed by SO. I will have to un-accept your answer then and award a bounty? Is that okay with you? So, you will have recognized for your effort as well. If yes, let me know and I can do the same. You can also have a look at my expected output for reference

Comment: The code is ugly. There are many repetitive values. And not sure about as to why to use pandas as a container for something already available as numpy array.

Comment: One last question regarding interpretation. If you look at my above updated plot (in my post), Do you think feature 6 (last feature) has the highest impact on moving the prediction to class 0? By magnitude, it is `smaller than Feature 3 which has -6.05`. I want to know which of negative class (class 0) features has high impact?

Comment: Yes it does. It's (1) the most influential feature altogether, and it's (2) the feature that's the most influantial in making this datapoint a `0` class.

Comment: I am experiencing the following error: explainer.expected_value[1]
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable

Comment: I am currently using version 0.41

Comment: sv.values[:,:,1].flatten()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[10], line 1
    sv.values[:,:,1].flatten()

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values'