# Plotting SHAP waterfall plot

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, classification, shap

I am trying to plot the SHAP waterfall plot for my dataset using the code below. I am working on binary classification problem.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from shap import TreeExplainer, Explanation
from shap.plots import waterfall

import shap

print(shap.__version__)

X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True, as_frame=True)

idx = 9
model = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=5, n_estimators=100).fit(X, y)
explainer = TreeExplainer(model)
sv = explainer(X.iloc[[idx]])   # pass the row of interest as df
exp = Explanation(
    sv.values[:, :, 1],         # class to explain
    sv.base_values[:, 1],
    data=X.iloc[[idx]].values,  # pass the row of interest as df
    feature_names=X.columns,
)
waterfall(exp[0])
```

But I get an error like below

> AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'items'

but when I manually try the values under `Explanation` object, they produce output successfully.

I guess the `Explanation` function is expecting something more but am missing it.

I verified that my `X` is a dataframe and my `y` is a Series as shown in the sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71751251/get-waterfall-plot-values-of-a-feature-in-a-dataframe-using-shap-package). `Shape of X is (2986, 29) and y is (2986,)`

Can help me understand what is the issue here?

**update - waterfall in dataframe. This works.**

```
explainer = TreeExplainer(model)
bv = explainer.expected_value[1]
sv = explainer(X, check_additivity=False)

sdf = pd.DataFrame({
    'row_id': X.index.values.repeat(X.shape[1]),
    'feature': X.columns.to_list() * X.shape[0],
    'feature_value': X.values.flatten(),
    'base_value': bv,
    'shap_values': sv.values[:,:,1].flatten()
})
```

Comment: Can you please provide more code? Like how `explainer` object is defined, `type(X)`, `X.shape`, and the line that throws error?

Comment: updated the post with code at the top, X.shape and y.shape at the bottom

Comment: I tried another code of yours which puts waterfall plot in dataframe (and that works). you can see the updated code at bottom. But if I use one of your other code to plot the waterfall with feature values, it threw the above error. which is also shown above

Comment: I suggest you put together a [reprex], either with a sample at github, or better [sklearn.dataset.make_classification](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_classification.html#sklearn.datasets.make_classification). Hard to tell without being able to reproduce your error

Comment: The problem is it is working with sample data breast cancer but am not sure what is the causing the issue for me to reproduce. But I did all the checks and found out that the datatypes match as is in sample data.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov - I realized that t threw error for breast cancer example as well. I updated my post with breast cancer example for you to try.

Comment: The updated code is verbatim copy from the earlier answer of mine that works perfectly. I do suggest putting together a start to finish [reprex] that throws the provided error.

Comment: Yes, I restarted my kernel and tried your code as is. I got the same error for breast cancer example as well. Not sure, whether my system environment is causing any issues or numpy version etc.

Comment: If I had known what causes the error, I would have provided the full example.